# Tensorflow automatcly input None in shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm learning TF. Starting with the mnist dataset. I have 10.000 images of 28*28 pixels. If i input that as a shape

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from matplotlib import pyplot
from tensorflow.keras import layers

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28))
```

If I print that I get

```
<tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(None, 28, 28) dtype=float32>
```

Why is there an element of None?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366871/tensorflow-placeholder-understanding-shape-none?rq=1 answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The None is just a placeholder saying that the network can input more
> than one sample at the time. None means this dimension is variable.
> The first dimension in a keras model is always the batch size. ...
>
> That's why this dimension is often ignored when you define your model.
> For instance, when you define input_shape=(100,200) , actually you're
> ignoring the batch size and defining the shape of "each sample".

see the original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64844529/understanding-the-values-of-summary-output-shape-param/64844794?noredirect=1#comment114662186_64844794)

Answer (score 0):

None is the batch size, which mean your model will train multiple images of 28,28 size at the same time. when you use .fit method in keras model you can specify batch size as parameter.